# Why need '//' in windows with git-bash to access container

Tags: git-bash

I am using git-bash in windows laptop, and I want to execute some CLI in POD.

But I got some error like:

```
$ kubectl -n bow exec $POD -- ls /tmp
ls: cannot access 'C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp': No such file or directory
command terminated with exit code 2
```

But if I use '//' in the path, it works:

```
$ kubectl -n bow exec $POD -- ls //tmp
busybox.tar.gz
```

Can anyone know the reason and how to avoid the error?

Comment: what OS are running in your pods? Windows?

Comment: the POD is running with Linux(UBI) based image.